# Updating state in receive function is ignored

Tags: solidity

At first I had a function called `deposit` and updating state was working fine:

```
function getPlayerCount() external view returns (uint256 count) {
  return playersLength;
}

function deposit() external payable {
  playerLength++;
}
```

However I want it to be easy to make ETH transfers to my smart contract without needing to know what function.

```
receive() external payable {
  playerLength++;
}
```

To call this function in tests I set up a helper since I could no longer simply do `myContract.deposit(..)`:

```
let myContract: MyContractType
let deposit: (weiAmount: string) => Promise<string>

before(async () => {
  const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners()

  deposit = (weiAmount: string) => {
    const hexWei = ethers.utils.hexlify(BigInt(weiAmount))

    return myContract.provider.call({
      from: owner.address,
      to: myContract.address,
      value: hexWei,
    })
  }
})
```

This works fine to call the `receive` function, however when I call the function it has no awareness of `playerLength` (always 0) and perfectly working tests from before fail:

```
await deposit(weiAmount)
expect(await myContract.getPlayerCount()).to.equal(1) // Stays on 0 despite updating to 1 inside `receive`
```

It seems that `receive` doesn't update state at all, but I can't find information about how to use or test this function, or if this is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method of most Ethereum libraries is only for querying/ reading state from the chain (see `eth_call` on https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API). To perform a state change you need to send a transaction and it need to be mined, therefore you need to use `sendTransaction` method.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the deposit method to the following and it made it stateful for some reason:

```
before(async () => {
  const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners()

  deposit = async (weiAmount: string) => {
    const hexWei = ethers.utils.hexlify(BigInt(weiAmount))

    return owner.sendTransaction({
      to: myContract.address,
      value: hexWei,
    })
  }
})
```